# Flatten a nested JSON array in ADF copy activity

Tags: arrays, json, azure-data-factory

How can I flatten an array of JSONs that contain another array inside it, in the copy activity. I review the forumns and samples. I've already tested many approaches, but it seems my JSON is very complecated. This is the JSON:

```
{
    "results": [{
            "label": "CA - SF",
            "disOrd": 6,
            "id": "1234",
            "stages": [{
                    "label": "R D",
                    "disOrd": 0,
                    "metadata": {
                        "isClosed": "true",
                        "probability": "0.0"
                    },
                    "id": "567",
                    "createdAt": "2023-05-22T13:31:50.317Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-05-30T16:07:47.170Z",
                    "arch": false,
                    "writePer": "CRM"
                }, {
                    "label": "P D",
                    "disOrd": 1,
                    "metadata": {
                        "isClosed": "true",
                        "probability": "0.0"
                    },
                    "id": "890",
                    "createdAt": "2022-10-21T10:04:15.298Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-05-30T16:07:47.170Z",
                    "arch": false,
                    "writePer": "CRM"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2021-07-19T16:06:35.682Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-05-30T16:07:47.170Z",
            "arch": false
        }, {
            "label": "IO",
            "disOrd": 14,
            "id": "2345",
            "stages": [{
                    "label": "P-D",
                    "disOrd": 0,
                    "metadata": {
                        "isClosed": "true",
                        "probability": "0.0"
                    },
                    "id": "987",
                    "createdAt": "2023-05-30T16:06:22.624Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-05-30T16:06:22.624Z",
                    "arch": false,
                    "writePer": "CRM"
                }, {
                    "label": "I C",
                    "disOrd": 1,
                    "metadata": {
                        "isClosed": "false",
                        "probability": "0.05"
                    },
                    "id": "876",
                    "createdAt": "2020-04-15T16:17:02.063Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-05-30T16:06:22.624Z",
                    "arch": false,
                    "writePer": "CRM"
                }, {
                    "label": "GI",
                    "disOrd": 2,
                    "metadata": {
                        "isClosed": "false",
                        "probability": "0.25"
                    },
                    "id": "543",
                    "createdAt": "2020-04-15T16:17:02.063Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2023-05-30T16:06:22.624Z",
                    "arch": false,
                    "writePer": "CRM"
                }               
            ],
            "createdAt": "2020-04-15T16:17:02.063Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-05-30T16:06:22.624Z",
            "arch": false
        }       
    ]
}
```

I want to copy the flatten JSON into a csv file.
I used a varaible that has the dynamic mapping in the copy activity, then its index has been changed in a loop but the problem occured with double quotes. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to copy hierarchical Json data which contain nested arrays using Copy activity in ADF.  This is possible up to one level of hierarchy by using collection reference option in mapping tab of Copy data activity.

As per this this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#hierarchical-source-to-tabular-sink)

[image]

To achieve your requirement, you need to use the data flow and the flatten trans formation.

- First create a data flow and add the source as your Json file.
- Take a flatten transformation and Under `Unroll by` select your arrays to be flatten and create appropriate columns using add mapping.
  [image]

**Output:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

**Using copy activity:**

As copy activity has limitation of flattening single array at a time you need to use two copy activities.

1. First flatten the result array. Take one copy activity and flatten result array as follow and store in the Json file.

- Source setting (take initial file in source)
  [image]
- Sink setting (store the flattened result array to another Json file)
  [image]
- Mapping should look like below:
  [image]
- Output stored in second json file is:
  [image]

2. Now flatten the stage array from our newly stored Json file. Take another copy activity and flatten stages array as follow and store in the csv file.

- Source setting (Json file stored in first copy activity)
  [image]
- Sink setting (store the flattened stages array to CSV file)
  [image]
- Mapping should look like below:
  [image]
- **Output stored in CSV file is:**
  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but based on our company's policies we shouldn't use data flow.

Comment: In Copy activity You can only flatten single array at a time.

Comment: please check the updated answer.